# How to install mpi4py on Windows 10 with msmpi

Tags: python, windows, mpi4py

I use Anaconda with python 3.7.2. My OS is Windows 10, I've installed MSMPI. When I'm trying to install mpi4py via Anaconda ( where only the 2.0 version is avalible), python downgrades to 3.6.8 version, which is not compatible with some of my projects. I'm trying to install mpi4py 3 using pip, but I receive an error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/. I've already installed it, but the problem hasn't solved. What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you need to install Visual Studio 2017 (https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=Community&rel=15) with the last SDK Win10 and C++ Dev Tools/

Secondly, install MPI Tools and SDK (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=57467)

At the end, print "pip install mpi4py" in cmd.exe

That's all:)

Comment: Make sure you install both MPI Tools and SDK, and add both paths to PATH. I only installed the SDK at the beginning, and it took me a while to figure out why mpiexec still didn't work...